# Facebook insights, page_fans_country accessible, no data for page_fans, page_fans_locale or page_fans_gender_age

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm using FQL to access pages insights and I've got different results depending on the metric I pass in the query.

For exemple, this query works correctly, I get the datas for any facebook pages :

SELECT value FROM insights WHERE object_id='PAGEID' AND metric='page_fans_country' AND end_time=end_time_date('2013-04-14T07:00:00+0000') AND period='0'

but if I use another metric like page_fans_gender_age or page_fans_locale, I don't get any data, except for one specific page (which is maybe related to my token).

I don't understand why the metric are working differently, I don't see any specific infos in the graph documentation about this ?

Are page_fans_country insights datas "public" but not the other metrics ?

Can it be a token problem ? Or does it depend on the end_time parameters ?

Is my problem related to this bug : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/345809555540652?browse=search_5148c3f9aa0392220388804

Answer (score 1):

Yes - `page_fans_country` is publicly available, the other metrics require an appropriately authenticated token. For what it's worth, I don't think `0` is valid for period, either.

Normally you can avoid `end_time` issues by selecting a date a few days in the past (Insights has a variable lag time, normally around 3 days).